# Elasticsearch aggregations in php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am writing Elasticsearch aggregations queries to find the total count available:

```
  GET zap/_search
  {
   "aggregations": {
   "Brand_Name_Count": {
     "terms": {"field": "brand_name", "size" : 0}
         },
   "Stock_Status_Count" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "stock_status", "size" : 50}
         },
   "Category_Id_Count" : {
       "terms" : { "field" : "category_id", "size" : 50}
         }
        }
      }
```

And I am getting the count properly.
How do i write these type of queries in php code??
As i am new to elasticsearch any help would be helpful
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking idea from github.
The agg (and search) PHP syntax follows the JSON API 1:1. So you can take your aggregation above and just translate it into PHP arrays like so:

```
$myQuery = [];  // Your query goes here

$params = [
    'index' => 'zap',
    'body' => [
        'aggs' => [
            'Brand_Name_Count' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field' => 'brand_name',
                    'size' => 0
                ]
            ],
            'Stock_Status_Count' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field' => 'stock_status',
                    'size' => 50
                ]
            ],
            'Category_Id_Count' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field' => 'category_id',
                    'size' => 50
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'query' => $myQuery
    ]
];

$results = $client->search($params);
```

Aggregations are executed in parallel to searches, so just specify your search query and you'll get back a search hits element as well as the aggs element